# Where is my Disk Space going?

Tags: lubuntu, disk-usage

I ran these 3 commands (concatenated into 1 huge command) to check where all my disk space was going in my home dir:

[image: commands and their output]
source: http://postimg.org/image/vmgndj62t/

If you see the size of /home/thebongy is 12 GB. Thus all the directories below that in the output should add up to about 12 GB. But they add up to like close to 11.1 GB. Why is this happening? WHere does the space go? Is there something wrong in my regex(grep)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sizes given from that command (which is really overcomplicated: you could just use `du -ahd 1 ~/ | sort -hr`
; notice that this command includes `/home` itself in the list) are printed in a "Human readable" form, and they are approximated. Run these commands and you'll see that the sum of the sizes in Bytes of all the files/folders inside `/home` will match the size in Bytes of `/home` itself, like its expected:

```
du -s ~/
```

(to see `/home`'s size in Bytes. `-s`: shows only the size and the name of the target file/folder)

```
du -ad 1 ~/ | sort -nr
```

(to see `/home`'s files and folders' size in Bytes ordered from the biggest file/folder to the smallest file/folder. `-a` in `du`: shows files in addition to folders, `-d 1` in `du`: only traverse the current folder with no recursion, `-n` in `sort`: sort the input numerically, `-r` in `sort`: sort the input in a reversed order. Notice that this command includes `/home` itself in the list)

Comment: It matches now! BTW, is there any way to get values in the human readable format with more decimal places(like atleast 3)?

Comment: @RishitBansal I edited the answer because removing `/home` with `grep` worked only if used against `/home` as the working directory (i.e. `du -ahd 1 | ...` and `du -ad 1 | ...`), anyway probably yes, but it'd require writing a shell script to re-elaborate the sizes provided in Bytes by `du`, let me see if i can manage to work out something, if i succed i'll add the script to the answer